# Unable to run insert stmt on object SQLErrorCode: 0

Tags: sql, ormlite, oncreate, create-table

I have model with many datafields which are identical with name in database.

I recive a Json, then mapping it to the Model (Succeful - ive checked in debug and model is not null and have the atributes) and then I want to create a record with it using `modelDAO.create(model)`, but I got a message

Unable to run insert stmt on object

> com.example.k: INSERT INTO `museum` (`id` ,`url` ,`museum_name`
>   ,`museum_x` ,`museum_y` ,`phone_number` ,`email` ,`short_name`
>   ,`qr_code` ,`created_at` ,`updated_at` ,`active` ,`opening_hours`
>   ,`description_short` ,`description` ,`app_url` ,`deleted` ,`source_id`
>   ,`language` ,`museum_group` ,`creator_id` ,`address` ,`country`
>   ,`city` ,`state` ,`zip` ,`street` ,`amenities` ,`parent_id`
>   ,`published` ,`meta_id` ,`logo` ,`subscription_id` ,`category_id`
>   ,`stripe_token` ,`slug` ,`distance` ,`creation_date` ,`update_date`
>   ,`group` ,`exhibitions` ,`museum_amenities` ) VALUES
>   (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

The error code is 0, and i double checked if the field and types are the same.

Comment: What's the full error?  Is there an exception?